# Upload images to cloud server like cloudinary/imgbb using tinymce text editor

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tinymce, richtextbox, wysiwyg

I am trying to implement tinymce richtext editor in a next js app. I want to know how to implement the image upload functionality where user could select an image from their local device, then the image will be uploaded in cloudinary or imgbb. What can i do to implement this functionality? This is the editor component.

```
<Editor
        apiKey=process.env.API_KEY
        onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
        init={{
          plugins: 'preview importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code    visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount help charmap quickbars emoticons',
          editimage_cors_hosts: ['picsum.photos'],
          menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
          toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontfamily fontsize blocks | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | image media template link codesample | ltr rtl',
          toolbar_sticky: false,
          toolbar_sticky_offset: 108,
          image_advtab: true,
          importcss_append: true,
          file_picker_callback: (callback, value, meta) => {
          
           
          },
          height: 600,
          image_caption: true,
          quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
          toolbar_mode: 'sliding',
          contextmenu: 'link image table',
          skin: 'oxide',
          content_css: 'default',
          content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px; background-color:teal }'
        }}
      />
```

What to do with the file_picker_callback? When i click the image button from toolsbar of the editor, a window popups but the file selector doesnot works, the file explorer does not opens.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.